# About Artificial Inteligence Search Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, tree

IDA* uses DFS or IDDFS?

[IDA*](http://intelligence.worldofcomputing.net/ai-search/iterative-deepening-a-star.html)  has an algorithm runing inside. Is it the DFS or the Iterative Deepening DFS? Or is it another different algorithm?
[second link](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/AI-Programming/IDA-Star.html)

Comment: "Iterative deepening A*" strongly suggests that it's IDDFS, but I'm just going by the name.

Answer (score 2):

IDA* is a variation of both `A*` and `ID-DFS`.

The difference from normal ID-DFS, is in IDA*, instead of limiting each iteration by the depth of the soludtion [the depth you are willing to look into, before restarting], it **limits each iteration** [of the deepening] **by the  f-costs** (g + h).

Comment: I didnt ask this. I know this stuff you wrote. I am asking which algorithm is IDA* using inside.

Answer (score 0):

IDA*, as its name suggests, is iterative deepening combined with A*.  That is, it uses A* limited to one-step paths, then two-step paths, then three-step paths, and so on until either a minimum step length solution is found or you run out of patience.